# Lacie petitekey write protected

Tags: macos, usb

I have a Lacie petitekey, and when I use it with my mac configuration (10.9.4) it says that the key is in read only.

I cannot format it as well, so I cannot really use it anymore regarding that it is impossible to put any data on it.

How can I be able to use it in write/read mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it was a failure of the key, I asked Lacie and they sent me another one.

So if you come across the same issue contact Lacie.

Comment: You should mark your question as answered.